# Use Image without adding it in WPF Project/Solution Resources

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am building a Gallery for Floors in WPF application, I am reading Image Names from csv file and User will directly copy Images into Resources folder.

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(
    (Application.Current as PlayOnSurface.App).ProjectAmenitiesCSVPath);
// browse the csv file line by line until the end of the file
while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
{
    // for each line, split it with the split caractere (that may no be ';')
    var splitLine = streamReader.ReadLine().Split('~');

    if (int.Parse(splitLine[0].Trim())
        == (Application.Current as PlayOnSurface.App).SelectedFloorID)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < splitLine.Length; i++)
        {
            ImageList.Add(splitLine[i].Trim());
        }
    }
    // map the splitted line with an entity
}
streamReader.Close();

btnPrev.IsEnabled = false;
if (ImageList.Count <= 1)
    btnNext.IsEnabled = false;
imgGallery.Source = Utilities.LoadBitmapFromResource(
    "Resources/Amenities/" + ImageList[0],
    null);
```

Utilities code

```
    public static BitmapImage LoadBitmapFromResource(string pathInApplication, Assembly assembly = null)
        {
            if (assembly == null)
            {
                assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
            }

            if (pathInApplication[0] == '/')
            {
                pathInApplication = pathInApplication.Substring(1);
            }
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/" + assembly.GetName().Name + ";component/" + pathInApplication, UriKind.Absolute));
        }
```

I can't add it in Resources folder in project and I can't embed resources because I want user to copy their file in Resources folder and update csv file after deployment.

My code will read it and display gallery but in that case WPF throws "Cannot locate resource" exception when loading the image on `imgGallery.Source` line in above code.

my csv file format:

```
1~FirstFloor~img1.png~img2.png~img3.png
2~SecondFloor~img1.png~img2.png~img3.png
3~ThirdFloor~img1.png~img2.png~img3.png
4~FourthFloor~img1.png~img2.png~img3.png
```

Comment: The code for `LoadBitmapFromResource` is probably going to be important.

Comment: If you can't embed the images as resources anyway - you might be fine by loading it directly from the filesystem...

Comment: There is a .Net library called TextfieldParser that takes care of parsing for any structured files.You need to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic in the Add References .NET tab. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Try this : In the solution explore set the image "Build Action" property to "Resource" ,then clean the solution and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use the file absolute path, simply change the last line of the `LoadBitmapFromResource` function to:

```
return new BitmapImage(new Uri(assembly.GetName().CodeBase + pathInApplication, UriKind.Absolute));
```

this should do the fix.
Also you can try using the `UriKind.Relative`.

Good day

Answer (score 0):

You're using an incorrect authority in your URI scheme. The application authority is to be used for data files which are known at compile time (aka static resources). You have to replace it with the siteoforigin authority.

I'd also recommend replacing your home-rolled text file format with a standard CSV file. Many programs such as Excel support generating comma-separated fields by default. While custom separators can be put, they usually require additional effort. Reading and parsing comma-separated files is also easier because many libraries are available to do these tasks.